# Looking for a database of plant features

Tags: botany, species-identification, database, species, data

To perform some private data science experiments I am looking for accessible information on morphological plant features (tabular information would be best). Crawling the web I found many websites with limited more general description and a lot of information on location and population data.

Do you know a website, institute or person in possession of such data and willing to share it? Since I am located in Germany my main interest is in the local flora, but any other would also do the job.

Answer (score 8):

-- **Traits** --

[**TRY**](https://www.try-db.org/TryWeb/Home.php)

TRY is a Plant Trait Database. More formally, it's a network of vegetation scientists headed by DIVERSITAS/IGBP, and the Max Planck Institute for Biogeochemistry, providing a global archive of curated plant traits.

[**BioTraits**](http://biotraits.ucla.edu/)

This is an online resource for empirical data on how biological traits respond to environmental drivers such as temperature, light, and salinity.

[**Nate Swenson**](http://www.swensonlab.com/research.html)

Nate and his collaborators have compiled a ton of traits for species all over the world (though focused on the tropics).

[**Coyle et al. 2014**](http://labs.bio.unc.edu/Hurlbert/pubs/Coyle%20et%20al%202014.pdf)

Appendix 2 of their 2014 Ecography paper lists primary literature sources and publicly available trait databases they used to examine 3 traits: leaf nitrogen, seed mass, and wood density.

-- **Images** --

[**Morphbank**](http://www.morphbank.net/)

An international Web database that contains thousands of high-resolution photographs and other images of plant and animal specimens.

[**Botanical Images Databases**](http://nickrentlab.siu.edu/BotImages.html)

This site provides dozens of links to databases containing plant images. There are also regional databases provided (e.g., [Pflanzenphotos.de](http://www.pflanzenphotos.de/start.htm)).

[**Botany.ch**](http://www.botany.ch/morphology.htm)

This site contains both text sources (e.g., lectures and essays) as well as links to morphology picture databases (e.g., [Botanical Image Database of the University of Basel](http://www.unibas.ch/botimage/)).

---

See also [**FAO Online Catalogues**](http://www4.fao.org/cgi-bin/faobib.exe?vq_query=D%3DPLANT%20MORPHOLOGY&database=faobib&search_type=view_query_search&table=mona&page_header=ephmon&lang=eng) for a number of morphological sources in both English and German.

Answer (score 2):

There is the TRY database of plant traits:

https://www.try-db.org/TryWeb/Home.php